# down arrow in HTML

Tags: asp.net, html, css

here is the code for right arrow in HTML (`&#187;`) and it will looks like ».Like this any other html code for down arrow and up arrow?

Comment: That isn't an arrow, it is a quotation mark. Don't use it as an arrow.

Comment: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice list of named entities:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

The numbers are just Unicode code points, so you could look them up there:
http://unicode.org/charts/

So, for example, down arrow would be `&darr;` (↓) and up arrow would be `&uarr;` (↑). Also, left arrow and right arrow are `&larr;` and `&rarr;`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's not an "arrow", it's a "quotation mark". The code for the "LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK" would be 171, but there's no "up" and "down" quotation marks.

For actual arrows, check something like this table: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arrows/utf8test.htm

Answer (score 2):

There are single arrows: ↑ (`&uarr;`, `&#8593;` or `&#x2191;`) and ↓ (`&darr;`, `&#8595;` or `&#x2193;`). There are also double arrows: ⇑ (`&uArr;`, `&#8657;` or `&#x21D1;`) and ⇓ (`&dArr;`, `&#8659;` or `&#x21D3;`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no corresponding double arrow that points upwards (keep in mind that » is actually a punctuation entity). But you may find this one useful - 8743 (∧ upward) and 8744    (∨ downward).
You may also find [this list of html entities](http://www.escapecodes.info/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

these are the HTML codes for

`(&#8593;)`single Upward arrow
`(&#8594;)` single Downward arrow

`(&#8657;)` Up Double Arrow
`(&#8659;)` Down Double Arrow